# Android端末の機種変時のregistrationIdの取り扱いについて

Tags: android, java, gcm

GCMを用いてAndroidアプリを作成しており、プッシュ通知送信のために、下記のコードにてregistrationIdを取得しており、SharedPreferencesに保存しております。

```
registrationId = gcm.register("xxxxx");
```

機種変の時など、バックアップツールなどを使ってアプリのデータを移管した場合、SharedPreferencesに保存されたregistrationIdも移管されます。

しかし、（機種変前に取得した）registrationIdでは、新しい端末へはプッシュ通知が送れません。

こういった場合、どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

Android Mからは、"full-backup-content"タグおよび"exclude"タグを使い、データ移管から特定データを除外方法もあるかと思いますが、targetSDKversion 23以上が対象なので、それ以前のバージョンの場合はどのように対処するのがベストでしょうか？

Comment: gcm.register() は、どのようなタイミングでコールしているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく質問当初と状況は変わっていると想いますが、https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid?hl=ja から引用します。

> クライアント アプリの更新: クライアント アプリを更新するときは、既存の登録 ID
>   が新しいバージョンで動作することが保証されないため、その ID を無効にする必要があります。おすすめの方法は、登録 ID
>   を保存する際に現在のアプリのバージョンを格納し、クライアント
>   アプリが起動された際に、この保存した値を現在のアプリのバージョンと比較することです。両者が一致しない場合は、保存されたデータを無効にして再度登録処理を開始します。
>
> バックアップと復元: クライアント アプリをバックアップする際は、登録 ID を保存しないでください。登録 ID は、クライアント
>   アプリの復元時まで有効のままであるとは限らず、登録 ID が無効であればクライアント
>   アプリも無効な状態になるからです（つまり、アプリでは登録済みであると認識されるものの、GCM ではその登録 ID
>   が保存されなくなるため、アプリでメッセージが取得されなくなります）。アプリが初めてインストールされるときのように、登録プロセスを開始する方法がおすすめです。

というわけで、機種変更前に取得したregstrationIdは無効になる可能性があるので、機種変更後にregistrationIdを取得・登録しなおしましょう。